# Accessing contents of cell in HTML table using children[]

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pull a specific value from the HTML of a cell in an HTML table. I have tried to use the .rows parameter, which didn't work (the JavaScript didn't run past the line that used `.row`) and I have currently settled on adding an `id` to the rows that I want to pull from, accessing those rows using `getElementById()`, and then trying to use `children[]` and `innerHTML` to get the value that I'm looking for. Below is my example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script>
var hits = document.getElementById("B2").children[4].innerHTML
alert(hits)
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="battingTable">
  <caption>Batting</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>AB</th>
      <th>R</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>2B</th>
      <th>3B</th>
      <th>HR</th>
      <th>RBI</th>
      <th>BB</th>
      <th>SO</th>
      <th>AVG</th>
      <th>OBP</th>
      <th>SLG</th>
      <th>OPS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="B2">
      <td>Player1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this technique also appears to fail, since a JavaScript alert *doesn't even show up on my page*, let alone display the correct value (`5`).

Is there another technique that I can use to access the value I am looking for? (My end goal is to access the two values in this table, divide one by the other, and then set another cell in the table to display that final calculated value.)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable. In particular, we need to see the JavaScript that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running, but it runs *before* most of the content loads, since it is in the `<head>` element. By moving it to the end of `<body>`, it will run the script after everything loads.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="battingTable">
  <caption>Batting</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>AB</th>
      <th>R</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>2B</th>
      <th>3B</th>
      <th>HR</th>
      <th>RBI</th>
      <th>BB</th>
      <th>SO</th>
      <th>AVG</th>
      <th>OBP</th>
      <th>SLG</th>
      <th>OPS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="B2">
      <td>Player1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    var hits = document.getElementById("B2").children[4].innerHTML
    alert(hits)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @MrDiamond! I've moved it down to the bottom of the `<body`, and now I'm trying to iterate the process over several rows using the `.rows` syntax, but the code is not running. Is this a similar issue of placement? My mini-script is here: `<script>
    var battingTable = document.getElementById("battingTable");
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
      var rhits = battingTable.rows[i].children[4].innerHTML;
      var ratbats = battingTable.rows[i].children[2].innerHTML;
      var ravg = rhits/ratbats;
      battingTable.rows[i].children[11].innerHTML = ravg;
    };
`

Comment: Your loop is not iterating the rows of the table and also you missed the closing `</script>` tag. Here is the working link of your codes that shows how you can iterate the rows of that table:
https://jsfiddle.net/9ofmxcza/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need id's. Just simply put the JavaScript codes at the end of the `body`. And it will work.

And also you need to put a semicolon`;` after each JS statement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <caption>Batting</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>AB</th>
      <th>R</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>2B</th>
      <th>3B</th>
      <th>HR</th>
      <th>RBI</th>
      <th>BB</th>
      <th>SO</th>
      <th>AVG</th>
      <th>OBP</th>
      <th>SLG</th>
      <th>OPS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    var hits = document.querySelectorAll('tr')[1].children[2].innerHTML;
    // Getting all the table rows and then using the 2nd row (index is 1 as it starts from 0)
    // The index of children also starts from 0 so when you are trying to get the 3rd cell you need to use 2 
    alert(hits);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```